# Need Inputs : Is it possible to take screenshot after each test step in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any approach of taking screenshot after every Assert verification?
Screenshot should be taken irrespective of assert pass or fail.

Need strong suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Driver.TakeScreenshot();`

You will need to find a file path to save your screenshot to, and save the file as well.

```
var screenshot = Driver.TakeScreenshot();
var filePathToSave = "C:\\Users\\YourFilePathHere";

// format as .png
screenshot.SaveAs(filePathToSave, ImageFormat.Png);
```

I recommend wrapping this in a method and calling it whenever you need to:

```
public void TakeScreenshot()
{
    var screenshot = Driver.TakeScreenshot();
    var filePathToSave = "C:\\Users\\YourFilePathHere";

    // format as .png
    screenshot.SaveAs(filePathToSave, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Then you can use it after an `Assert` like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(something);
Driver.TakeScreenshot();
```

You will also need to handle the case where your `Assert` statement fails -- so you will need to implement this in a `[TearDown]` method as well, to ensure the screenshot gets taken even when the test fails:

```
    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        // take screenshot
        TakeScreenShot();

        // close and quit driver
        Driver.Close();
        Driver.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: The question is not about how to take screenshot but about how to take it on every assertion

Comment: There is no way to wrap `Assert` as it is part of the NUnit or test framework namespace. I provided code on how to take a screenshot after every assertion, including in the scenario where the assertion fails.

Comment: Assert("something");
takeScreenShot();

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nunit. It supports multiple asserts.

Excerpt from the documentation (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Multiple-Asserts)

> The multiple assert block may contain any arbitrary code, not just
>   asserts.
>
> Multiple assert blocks may be nested. Failure is not reported until
>   the outermost block exits.
>
> If the code in the block calls a method, that method may also contain
>   multiple assert blocks.

Sample Use:

```
[Test]
public void ComplexNumberTest()
{
     ComplexNumber result = SomeCalculation();
     Assert.Multiple(() =>
     {
         Assert.AreEqual(5.2, result.RealPart, "Real part");
         Assert.AreEqual(3.9, result.ImaginaryPart, "Imaginary part");
     });
}
```

Hope this helps.